# Flutter: catch ClientException (connection closed before full header was received) before app crashes

Tags: flutter

I've been getting that error, when my server was not sending the http response. So, I'd tried to catch that and display with a snack bar by using `Try-Catch`.

However, I still receive the error and my flutter app get frozen. How can I correctly use `Try-Catch` in order to prevent the app crashes and display a snack bar?

```
 // connect to the backend and create user account
    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        '${Env().basedUrl}${Env().user}',
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(
          <String, String>{
            'user_id': '',
            'user_email': '',
            'user_first_name': '',
            'user_last_name': '',
          },
        ),
      );
      var fbAuth = json.decode(response.body);
    print(fbAuth);
 
    } on TimeoutException catch (_) {
      SnackBarFail()
          .snackBarFail('Server Failed', 'Please, try it again later!');
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
     
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you are `await`ing the response of `http.post`, the error is still occurring asynchronously. Therefore, you must catch it accordingly.

```
var response = await http.post(
  '${Env().basedUrl}${Env().user}',
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(
    <String, String>{
      'user_id': '',
      'user_email': '',
      'user_first_name': '',
      'user_last_name': '',
    },
  ),
).catchError((error) {
  // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Incorrect. The `await` keyword before `http.post` will re-throw the error if the async context throws an error. The original code is fine.